# Message wont connect to method

Tags: objective-c

I'm kind of new to this, so it  might be a beginners mistake. The problem is that when i send a message to a method it doesn't connect.

Here's the calling method:

```
-(BOOL) login:(LoginInfo *) info{

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@?name=%@&password=%@", FAMORABLE_API_URL,FAMORABLE_API_ACTION_LOGIN, info.username, info.password];

NSDictionary* json =  [self getJson:url];
NSString *token = [json objectForKey:@"Token"]; 

NSLog(@"results: %@", token);

LoginInfo *loginResult = [LoginInfo alloc];
loginResult.token = token;
//TODO
NSLog(@"test 1 %@", loginResult.token);
    [clientService saveLoginInfo:loginResult];

return YES;

}
```

On the line above the last you can see I'm sending to saveLoginInfo in clientService which is declared in ClientService.h which is imported in this file.

```
-(void) saveLoginInfo:(LoginInfo *)info{
NSLog(@"test 2 %@", info);
NSLog(@"test 3%@", info.token);
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


[defaults setObject:info.token forKey:KEY_TOKEN];
NSString *string = [defaults stringForKey:KEY_TOKEN];
NSLog(@"test 4%@", string);
// save it
[defaults synchronize];


if (!(info.token)){
    self.currentUser = nil;
    self.isLoggedOn=false;
}else{
    self.currentUser = info;
    self.isLoggedOn=true;
}    
}
```

This is the method being called. I've put out a bunch of logs, mostly as a safe if i did one wrong, but none of them are being executed...

Do you have any ideas of what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance
Tom

Comment: Does the `clientService` field exist yet, or is it `nil`?  (Try to log just before the call, e.g. `NSLog(@"clientService = %@", clientService);`.)  In Objective-C a message sent to a `nil` value does nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `clientService` in the line `[clientService saveLoginInfo:loginResult];` an instance variable in your class?

If so, make sure that you have instantiated the object somewhere before you call it. (Either in your class's `init` method, or possibly `viewDidLoad` if it's a `UIViewController`.)

E.g.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    clientService = [[MyClientService alloc] init];
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        clientService = [[MyClientService alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

(Make sure you also release the instance in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: He could even use lazy initialization, but making the getter instantiate the variable if it's nil.

Comment: Forgot to mention... Backendservice (the class im calling from) is more or less a library of functions. It doesn't have a view, and i couldn't find an init method either.

Comment: init is a method declared in NSObject. Assuming that your Backendservice is a subclass of NSObject, you can override init in your class. I will edit the answer to give an example.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit further @The dude?

Comment: @user1534948 sure. Imagine clientService is a property from your class. If you implement the getter, it will be something like:
-(MyClientService*) clientService{
if(clientService==nil){clientService = [[MyClientService alloc] init];}
return clientService;
}

That way first time you call self.clientService, if it is not instantiated it will instantiate it and then return it. After that, it will always return the instance that was created. That's called lazy instantiation or lazy initialization. EDIT: Note that way you have to access the property with self. notation (self.clientService)

Comment: It worked!
Thanks both of you, have been going crazy over this the last few days...